# Google Appscript append data from Queryimport to FK the Col C needs to be checked and appended in Col D no duplication

Tags: javascript, sourceforge-appscript

``
This is my function details any help would be appreciated

```
    **function calling**
    function appendDataIfNotExists() {
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("QueryImport");
     var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("FK");
     
     var data1 = sheet1.getRange("C6:C").getValues();
     var data2 = sheet2.getRange("D6:D").getValues();
     
     var newData = [];
     **Traversing**
     for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
       var valueToAppend = data1[i][0];
       **appending**
       // Skip empty or null values
       if (valueToAppend !== null && valueToAppend !== "" && valueToAppend !== "Ppppppppp") {
         if (!data2.some(function(row) { return row[0] === valueToAppend })) {
           newData.push([valueToAppend]);
         }
       }
     }
     
     if (newData.length > 0) {
       sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow() + 1, 4, newData.length, 1).setValues(newData);
     }
```

``/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question from `Google Appscript append data from Queryimport to FK the Col C needs to be checked and appended in Col D no duplication` and `This is my function details any help would be appreciated`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? And also, can you provide the details of your current issue? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike Suppose i have ID no-001 in Col C in Sheet Named QueryImport and I have another sheet Named FK where in Col D there is ID no -001 so I want to check the data in Col D of my Sheet2 and if any row entry does not  matches with Col C in my sheet1 then only append the   new record entry of col C in col D else don't append I hope this clears

Comment: Basically check each record In Col C of Sheet1 with Col D of sheet2 if record matches then don't append if don't then only append handling the duplication clause

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you could forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike No Problem Bud I will write this way: I need to refresh the data from Col C (Sheet1)  into Col D (Sheet2) and repeated entry should not be there

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill again. In your reply, 4 sheets of `QueryImport`, `FK`, `Sheet1`, and `Sheet2` are used. And, your latest reply, it seems that the sheets `QueryImport` and `FK` are not used. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between those 4 sheets. Can I ask you about the details of the 4 sheets? And, in your question, you want to use only columns "C" and "D" and want to ignore other columns. Is my understanding correct?